# Returning SQL rows with data concated per row in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In access I have a table that is like

```
ID| ROOMS | NOTES|
78|    234|      |
3 |    231|  key |
78|    195|      |
3 |    164|      |
```

I want to a sql query that will take the ID and combine them into one row each so it is like

```
78 -> 234,195
3->231, 164 -> key
```

i just want to combine the rows only in the query no into a new table

Comment: Where are you getting 192 from?

Comment: I don't understand how you would get the 195 in the 3 result, is that supposed to be 164?. And the 192 in the 78 result is supposed to be 195, right?

Comment: @hamlin11 @mu is too short, Yes it was a mistake sorry but i just a query that works in access that will combine those 2 rows and give you just one row instead of a bunch of rows together it is for a report

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a group_concat function in ms-access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have to build a function to do this, but thankfully access supports the use of VBA functions inside of your SQL query.

For example function to concatenate the rim's together based on a given ID would be as follows:

```
Public Function MyRooms(lngID As Variant) As Variant

   Dim rstRooms         As DAO.Recordset

   If IsNull(lngID) Then Exit Function

   Set rstRooms = "select Rooms from tblBookings where id = " & lngID
   Do While rstRooms.EOF
      If MyRooms <> "" Then MyRooms = MyRooms & "->"
      MyRooms = MyRooms & rstRooms!Rooms
      rstRooms.MoveNext
   Loop
   rstRooms.Close

End Function
```

Now your query can look like this:

```
Select id, MyRooms([id]) as Rooms, Notes from some table.
```

You can also make an identical function much the same for the notes column, and again simply place that in the above query.

Comment: This is not a macro. Access has macros and also has VBA (they are separate concepts and have separate meanings in Access).

So, the above is VBA code that would be placed inside of a standard code module.  You thus Insert a code module from the main Access menu or ribbon. You then paste in the above VBA code into that module.