# MS Access Database Query help required

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an access database with over 210k records. they are a list of product codes. with associated product codes. I want to create an access query that associates only one product code per line but merges the associated products into a single column matched to that product code but sepertaed by a , (comma)

Example of columns in access database

```
Product code: Associated product 
100000 2548741
100000 4578214
100000 1254712
100000 5687412
100000 1469787 
100000 9874582
100000 5478126
```

I want the following

```
Product code: Associated product 
100000 2548741,4578214,1254712,5687412,1469787 ,9874582, 5478126
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for a GROUP_CONCAT like solution:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do in vba:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318642

Answer (score 1):

Create a SQL query that retrieves the data that you want.
Use some client-side code to format the data the way you want.

SQL is used to manipulate (retrieve, add, remove, update) data, not to format it in a specific output format.