# Subquery in Access

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys, subquery, primary-key

I have 2 tables in Access with these fields

```
Student:
ID(PK)   Name   Family Tel

Lesson:
ID StudentRef(FK(Student))  Name    Score
```

Imagine  we have these records

```
Student :
1     Tom      Allen      09370045230
2     Jim      leman      09378031380

Lesson:

1     1       Math           18
2     1       Geography      20
3     2       Economic       15 
4     2       Math            12
```

How can I write a query that result will be this (2 fields)?

```
Tom      Math : 18    , Geography 20
Jim      Economic :15 ,  Math :12
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601643/access-sql-query-to-concatenate-rows/8603245#8603245

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.Name, l.Name, l.Score
  INNER JOIN tbl_lessons as l ON s.student_id = l.student_id
FROM tbl_students as s
```

That won't give you your formatting, but it'll get you the data.

Comment: no anybody can help me ? i can solve that in my application  but this is easy for me

Answer (score 0):

The most tricky part of your problem is how to aggregate strings in your sub-query. MS Access does not have any aggregation function that is applicable to strings (except for `Count()`) and there is no way to define your own function. This means you can't just get the desired "subject:score , subject:score" concanetation. As long as you can go without you can easily take the solution provided in the answer by Corith Malin.

Comment: thank Alexander Galkin and Corith Malin. i 'll solve it in my Application with DataTable .