# How to Combine field of different row in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a group_concat function in ms-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access)
>   [Ms Access Query: Concatenating Rows through a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query)

I have following table:

```
ID    TAG
----------
1     AAA
1     BBB
2     CCC
2     DDD
2     EEE
```

I want to get following as Output:

```
1    AAA, BBB
2    CCC, DDD, EEE
```

How can get result in the combination field in MS-Access.

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query will help with your query.

Comment: All methods at the above link show Result using VB code, not using MS-Access.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this in SQL alone with Jet/ACE, the database commonly used as a back-end to MS Access. You will have to use VBA. The examples shown use VB **A**, the code used by MS Office products, including MS Access.