# Grouping Column result set

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Select [Trader],[Reference] , [Type of Establishment], [Fruit Sold], [Stat Licence]
from Tablex
where [Type of Establishment]='D/03288'
and [Stat Licence]='Licenced'
```

Figure 1 - Sample results

```
Trader,Reference , Type of Establishment, Fruit Sold, Stat Licnece 
Lady Daves Foxes,  D/03288, Licenced, Bananas , Y_T_177
Lady Daves Foxes,  D/03288, Licenced, Apples , Y_T_177`
Lady Daves Foxes,  D/03288, Licenced, Pears , Y_T_177`
```

Now how do I get the result set below in Microsoft Access changing the sql view?

Figure 1 - What I want ?

`Trader,Reference , Type of Establishment, Fruit Sold, Stat Licnece`

`Lady Daves Foxes,  D/03288, Licenced, Bananas,Apples,Pear , Y_T_177`

Suppose I need the pivot the Fruit sold column somehow ?

Comment: If you can use vba functions the first answer to this post gives a solution: [Microsoft Access condense multiple lines in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843)

Comment: 1st choice is modifying sql using the SQL View window. Thanks for the post. Don't have much experience implementing these functions is sql so looks scary.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for a group_concat, but this does not exist in Access.

Nevertheless, there are workarounds which have been discussed here before.

E.g. [is there a group_concat function in ms-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access)

Hope this helps
R