# How to get a column with the grouped info of rows with the same id?

Tags: sql, ms-access, grouping

How can I group multiple rows of data?

My data structure is similar to:

```
ID        NAME       PhoneNo
1         Jon        8798765
2         Jon        3134684
3         Adams      7968434
4         Phil       3435435
5         Thomas     6734354
6         Jon        2343545
7         Jeff       3435424
8         Adams      3434354
```

I need to use SQL to group the information so I get something like this:

```
ID        NAME       PhoneNo
1         Jon        8798765,3134684,2343545
3         Adams      7968434,3434354
4         Phil       3435435
5         Thomas     6734354
7         Jeff       3435424
```

See what I did there? I de-duplicated and added all the phone numbers on the same field, comparing the names: Same name= same person, so put all the names on the same cell.
I'm currently using MS access, but I guess any other variant could work (I can find the equivalency)

Comment: I agree with Gord ... but wish to add that your field `ID` doesn't appear to add any value, so it doesn't belong in the result.  If it IS supposed to add value, then you had better think about what will happen to `2`, '6', '8', etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is mySQL function `GROUP_CONCAT`

If you are in Access, just use some kind of Macro inspired by this: [is there a group_concat function in ms-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access) or for MSSQL [Emulating MySQL’s GROUP_CONCAT() Function in SQL Server 2005](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html)

There is a Question, what are you really need.