# Query to merge multiple results into single record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a new database in Access 2010 for a help desk. I have an employees table along with a table for desktops, monitors, laptops, cell phone, etc.. that show the specs, the user, and a service tag. I need to create a query that matches the employees table to the other tables to show in each column what tech each employee has as just the service tag. The only problem is some employees have multiple of each tech and show up as multiple records in the query. I need it to show two desktop service tags in one cell that came from two records in the desktops table. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: This will be closest to what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access - It's easier done in other RDBMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)