# Access - Concatenating values in column where value in another column is the same

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following table in Access (from a query):

```
Ref     Score
ET/21     7
ET/21     6
ET/21     7
ET/25     3
ET/25     5
```

I want to create another table from it (or do it in the query), where I have the following instead (i.e. all the values for each ref are in the same cell concatenated with ',' between:

```
 Ref     Score
ET/21     7, 6, 7
ET/25     3, 5
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: You're looking for the equivalent of MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, which does not exist in Access.  One workaround would be to write a custom function which does this, and you can read about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access).

Comment: Excellent, thank you Tim! Much appreciated... I will check it out

Comment: I found a easy way to do it in Python, going to do it there instead :)

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out!