# Excel - Concatenate cell based other column

Tags: excel

I have 3 column that I want to gorup it hierarichal.

Column : `delivery_order_tli_id` is parent.
Column : `delivery_order_hanwa_id` is child of parent.
COlumn : `coil_ids` is concatenate based child of parent.

This is the data.

```
FLAT DATA       

delivery_order_tli_id   delivery_order_hanwa_id     coil_id
        1                       1                     108
        1                       1                     114
        1                       1                     116
        1                       1                     120
        1                       1                     123
        1                       1                     130
        1                       1                     163
        2                       1                     113
        2                       1                     115
        2                       1                     117
        2                       1                     119
        2                       1                     129
        2                       1                     131
        2                       1                     161
        3                       3                     171
        3                       221                   2880
        3                       221                   2881
        3                       221                   2887
        3                       221                   2889
        3                       221                   2890
        4                       4                     236
        4                       4                     237
        4                       4                     238
        4                       4                     239
        4                       4                     244
        4                       4                     245
        4                       5                     246
        4                       4                     253
```

Into like this :

```
    MERGE DATA (RESULT)     

delivery_order_tli_id   delivery_order_hanwa_id                     coil_ids
            1                       1                   108, 114, 116, 120, 123, 130, 163
            2                       1                   113, 115, 117, 119, 129, 131, 161
            3                       3                   171
            3                       221                 2880, 2881, 2887, 2889,2890
            4                       4                   236, 237,238,239, 244, 245, 253
            4                       5                   246
```

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a group\_concat function in ms-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access)

Comment: I can't imagine there being a way to do this in pure Excel, and even if there were, it would likely be so ugly that you wouldn't want it anyway.  Follow the duplicate link above for a way to simulate group concat database functionality using VBA.