# Combine multiple rows into a single row in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I have a the following data set built from query

```
col 1      col 2     col 3      col 4
a          1         1          1
a          1         1           2
c          1         2           3
c          1         2           4
C          1         5           4
```

What I would like my export to look like (am trying to move it to excel) is as follows:

```
col 1      col 2     col 3      col 4
a          1         1          1,2
c          1         2,5        3,4
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Another one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852892/is-there-a-group-concat-function-in-ms-access

Comment: Just FWIW - the idea to put commas in `col 3` is against the `1NF` and is extremely not recommended to be done in any DB.